# sqlite in memory db on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, in-memory-database

Is it possible to have a sqlite db in memory in iOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works as you'd expect within iOS - you can simply open an in-memory database using `:memory:` instead of the file name, [as per usual](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

That said, you'll obviously need to be aware of the amount of memory you're using due to the lower available memory level.